# Maya viewport navigation in 2.80?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

I'm totally new to Blender and I was wondering if there is a way to set up the viewport so I navigate like in Maya: Alt+mouse buttons.

I found the keymap in the preferences, deactivated the defaults for View3D Rotate, Move and Zoom, created new ones, Alt+LMB, MMB, RMB. Sadly they don't work.

Answer (score 5):

Blender does have this industry standard keymap (and has had it for years).

In blender 2.8 and up head to the user preferences, *Edit* > *User Preferences*.

Then in the *Keymap* tab change the key configuration to "*Industry Compatible*".

[image: Keymap tab of the User Preferences in 2.8]

---

In older versions of blender open up the User Preferences, *File* > *User Preferences*. Go to the *Input* tab and change the key configuration to "*Maya*".

[image: Input tab of the User Preferences in 2.79]

That is it. Now the viewport navigation, and many other shortcuts will act like other industry standard programs (maya).

Comment: In 2.91, that option seems to have disappeared. An idea where I can find it again ? Thanks

Comment: @LaurentCrivello The "Industry Compatible" keymap is still in blender 2.9x just as it was in 2.8x

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the "View3D Rotate Modal" other similarly named items I should have edited the 3D View/3D View (Global)/Rotate View. It works now but I'll still have to take care of the function collisions.